# How to configure linking in Web 8?

Tags: web8, dynamic-linking, topology-manager

I have installed DXA 1.4 on Web8 (CU1). Its all working fine, and as part of development I added a bunch of baseUrls for my web app: http://localhost:1234, http://somedomain.local, http://otherdomain:1234 and so on) using Set-TtmWebsite powershell scriptlet so I can run the site from local dev env, and also access the site running on a central web server with a variety of domains and ports.

I noticed that the dynamic links resolved are not relative; they have the a domain and port prefixed on them. This is causing problems as the domain/port is always the same; http://localhost:1234, no matter what domain/port is in the URL request, this means the links are broken when I request the site from http://otherdomain:1234 (as they all point to localhost)

I gathered from the docs you can override TTM behaviour by setting `OverrideDiscoveryService` to true in `cd_link_conf.xml` and thus have all resolved links relative to the site root, rather than with a domain/port added.

I tried this but with no joy - the . In fact, the domain/port prefix used actually changed from localhost:1234 to otherdomain:1234. After making the change I ran the `discover-registration.jar` update and restarted the discovery, content and web applications.

So the question is how does TTM determine the domain/port used for linking, and how can I change this (either in topology manager, or how do I get it to use the configuration from `cd_link_conf.xml`)

Update: After restarting everything again it works, so I obviously missed something. However the question remains about if you allow TTM to configure linking, how does it work out which domain/port to use?

Comment: BTW: Consider installing DXA 1.5; it's Bigger, Better and Faster. ;-)

Comment: I needed to restart the application pool for the DXA website in order for the Content service config change to kick in.

Answer (score 5):

If your website has multiple base URLs, you should indeed configure CD Linking to use relative URLs (as a matter of fact, I don't see why you would ever want to use absolute URLs).

Using absolute URLs with multiple website base URLs just won't work; CD Linking doesn't know your current context and hence can only select an arbitrary base URL.