# Configure CD linking "OverrideDiscoveryService" in code?

Tags: dynamic-linking, content-delivery

The configuration file `cd_linking_conf.xml` has [an `OverrideDiscoveryService` setting](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15122/how-to-configure-linking-in-web-8). Can this be configured in code, or in the Web.config?

Comment: This config is present in content service and I think you can use a placeholder for this configuration and set value using environmental variable to be used by content service. Is this helpful?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this sdl [article](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B71CBC5B-0ACA-4317-BA71-490BFBB461E1)(Mappings from Publications to URLs used to be configured in cd_link_conf.xml and cd_dynamic_conf.xml. The new Content Delivery architecture lets you store such mappings in Topology Manager, from which the Discovery Service can retrieve them. You can configure which of these places is used in your upgraded setup.)